# Use formulas in query function in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

What has been tried so far :

```
=query(dataset, "select Col1 where Col1='"&left(C1,3)&"' and Col2 is not null")
```

What I am trying to do :

```
=query(dataset, "select "&left(&"Col1"&,3)&" where Col1='"&left(C1,3)&"' and Col2 is not null")
```

I am trying to find display only first 3 letters of returned Column. I might want to use other formulas too. Is it a possibility in Google Sheets Query?

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **EDIT**: (following OP's request)

You can use (replacing `C2:C10` with your corresponding column) the following:

```
=QUERY({ArrayFormula(LEFT(C2:C10,3)),dataset}, "select Col1, Col3 where  Col4 is not null")
```

---

**Original answer**

Try this formula instead:

```
=ArrayFormula(LEFT(QUERY(dataset, "select Col1 where Col2 is not null"),3))
```

You don't have to put the function `LEFT` inside the `QUERY`.

Comment: What if there are two or more columns that I want to select? Like select Col1,Col2 and I wish to display only first 3 letters of Col1?

Comment: Please check the updated formula